# jaxb single element in array

Tags: jaxb, jersey

I'm using JAXB/Jersey (1.3) to convert java to json in a REST API. The java class I'm returning is like:

```
public class MyClass {  
  List<String> myTags;
  public List<String> getMyTags() {
    return myTags;
  }
}
```

My problem is that if there is only a single element in the list *myTags*, then the data is converted to json as a string object, not an array of strings.  That is, I get:

```
{
  "myTags": "myString"
}
```

What I want is:

```
{
   "myTags": ["myString"]
}
```

Anyone know whats up ?

Comment: Which library are you using for converting JAXB annotated classes to JSON?

Comment: Sun JAXB Reference Implementation, v2.1.12

Comment: Yeah, but which library do you use to convert the class to JSON? JAXB converts classes to XML, you need another library to convert to JSON, such as Jettison or Jackson

Comment: I'm using Maven, and only specifying the jersey dependencies, so I'm not explicitly specifying a library. However, looking at the resulting WAR file created, I'm assuming that Jersey is pulling in Jackson as a dependency (v1.7.1).

Comment: Yep, its Jackson :- the dependencies are listed in here: http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/jersey/jersey-json/1.6/jersey-json-1.6.pom

Comment: The link you have provided also has a dependency to Jettison, that has the problem you mentioned ( single element array rendered as non-array in Json). Can this help: http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Single-Element-Arrays-and-JSON-td5532105.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per Luciano's comments, the problem lies in the fact that Jersey wasn't using Jackson as the default JSON converter. I tried excluding Jettison from the pom dependency, but it still didn't resolve the issue. I found an answer to explicitly tell Jersey to use Jackson here:

[How can I customize serialization of a list of JAXB objects to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199453/how-can-i-customize-serialization-of-a-list-of-jaxb-objects-to-json/3143214#3143214)

Answer (score -1):

I was facing the similar issue and found simple fix. Marking @JsonSerialize instead of @XmlRootElement has worked for me.

```
@JsonSerialize
public class MyClass {  
  List<String> myTags;
  public List<String> getMyTags() {
    return myTags;
  }
}
```