# Jaxb json missing brackets for one element array

Tags: json, jaxb, brackets

I'm using JAXB/Jersey (1.3) to convert java to json in a REST API.
I read a lot about this problem, I tryed this [solution](http://blogs.oracle.com/japod/entry/missing_brackets_at_json_one), it work a half:

```
@XmlRootElement  
public class ArrayWrapper    
{  
        public List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();  
}
```

and my ContextResolver:

```
@Provider  
public class JAXBContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {  

        private JAXBContext context;

        private Class[] types = {ArrayWrapper.class,Wrapper.class};

        public JAXBContextResolver() throws Exception {

            MappedBuilder builder = JSONConfiguration.mapped();
            builder.arrays("list");
            builder.rootUnwrapping(true);
            this.context = new JSONJAXBContext(builder.build(), types);
}
```

ArrayWrapper aw=new ArrayWrapper();
aw.list.add("test");

I get {"list":["test"]} so it works but when I wrapp ArrayWrapper in an other class it don't work:

```
@XmlRootElement  
public class Wrapper  
{  
    public ArrayWrapper aw;

    public Wrapper()
    {
        aw=new ArrayWrapper();
        aw.list.add("test");
    }
}
```

new Wrapper();
I get {"aw":{"list":"test"}}

Anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: I used this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199453/how-can-i-customize-serialization-of-a-list-of-jaxb-objects-to-json), the first answer to the post works

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if you got it working so I am contributing my bit.

I also stumbled upon this issue recently. I found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3143214/1108032) in stackoverflow that helped me, but even more helpful was this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/wa-aj-jackson/index.html?ca=drs-) (introducing Jackson might help).

I hope this helps you, too. For me it was a matter of 5 minutes to fix the issue.