# Jersey: Can not deserialize instance of ArrayList out of String

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

I have a json based REST Web Service implemented using:
Jetty, Jersey, Jersey-JSON using Jackson.

One of my methods receives a Person instance, which has a field of type List<String>.
i.e.:

```
Public class Person {
    List<String> names;
}
```

If I call it with an array of names, all works ok! e.g.:

```
{ "names" : [ "Jhon", "Doe" ] }
```

But if the person has only one name, my client creates a single value element, e.g.:

```
{ "names" : "Jhon" }
```

When I try to call the service with a single value, I get an exception:

```
Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token
```

**Question:**

How should I create/configure my web service, in order to be able to deserialize array field when they are sent to me as a single element.

--

I already read:

[Jackson deserialization - with contained ArrayList<T>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978748/jackson-deserialization-with-contained-arraylistt)

and

[How can I customize serialization of a list of JAXB objects to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199453/how-can-i-customize-serialization-of-a-list-of-jaxb-objects-to-json/3143214#3143214)

and this that refer the last answer:

[Jersey client can not deserializable json services - exception(can not deserialize instance)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13775881/jersey-client-can-not-deserializable-json-services-exceptioncan-not-deseriali)

[Jaxb json missing brackets for one element array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6386873/jaxb-json-missing-brackets-for-one-element-array)

But none of those fix the problem.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After a long day, and another... after reading lots of wikis and faqs, it finally works.

What I did:

1. Use Jackson
2. Force Jackson providers usage
3. Define custom deserializer
4. activate the ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY flag
5. Fix dependencies

The story:

I was using Jersey 1.13 that uses (I belive) jaxb by default.

I changed it to **use Jackson**

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

as described at:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13895768/660990

This made my jersey use jackson, but the problem remains; jackson can't deserializer the array yet.

I forced the usage of **Jackson providers**:

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>
        your.project.packages;
        org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
</init-param>
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3143214/660990

Was a needed step, but not enough. It's necessary to activate the **ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY** flag.

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper;
objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
```

I needed define **custom deserializer**

```
public class MyResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

@Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(final Class<?> objectType) {
        ...            
        return objectMapper;
    }
}
```

in order to do that:

[Customizing-ObjectMapper](http://jersey.576304.n2.nabble.com/Customizing-ObjectMapper-td6234597.html)

After doing all of this it still didn't work...

After some more search time, I found:

[Jackson 2.0 with Jersey 1.12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668597/jackson-2-0-with-jersey-1-12)

That discusses **dependencies problems**..

This reveled my problem, **Jersey v1.13** ships with **Jackson v1.9.2 I need Jackson v2.0**

I removed dependency for jersey-json, because it included jackson 1.9.2:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

And directly declared dependency for:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Reference:

[jackson-jaxrs-json-provider](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jaxrs-json-provider)

**Note:** this change removes the Jersey ability to use Jaxb or jettison.

**Off topic**, may be interesting for someone:

[Configure Jersey/Jackson to NOT use @XmlElement field annotation for JSON field naming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5005668/configure-jersey-jackson-to-not-use-xmlelement-field-annotation-for-json-field)

Comment: Thanks mate, the following line solved my problem: objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);

Comment: @mojsilo where are you putting the 

**objectMapper = new ObjectMapper().configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);**

?

Comment: I've put it in the constructor of the service 
mapper.configure(  org.codehaus.jackson.map.DeserializationConfig.Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY,true);

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with annotations at class, field or method level using the [JsonFormat](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.html) annotation

```
@JsonFormat(with = Feature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY)
protected List<String> list;

public List<String> getList() {
    return list;
}

public void setList(List<String> list) {
    this.list = list;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Example 5.10 and 5.11 of [this page](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/json.html#d4e987) explain your exact problem. You can configure the JSON builder to force arrays for single-item lists, like so:
`JSONConfiguration.mapped().arrays("names").build()`.

Comment: Thank you! But I want to fix this in server side. Updated my question to be explicit.

Comment: Where would you add  **JSONConfiguration.mapped().arrays("names").build()**
in the client?  When you have constructed the request, but before sending it?

Answer (score 1):

It worked for me by adding @JsonSerialize to the class

```
@JsonSerialize
Public class Person {
    List<String> names;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
{"results": {"place": {"lang": "en-US","woeid": "2168606"}}}
```

&

```
{"results": {"place": [{"lang": "en-US","woeid": "2168606"}, {"lang": "en-US","woeid": "2168606"}]}}
```

this type how to do ...when using yahoo place api