# Jersey POST Rest service not able to accept an object containing a HashMap

Tags: java, json, rest, jersey

I have created a simple POST REST webservice that uses a composite object called Track that contians a HashMap inside it.
However when I test it using POSTMAN and pass JSON string then it doesnt deserialize the hashmap present in the json to the TestObj POJO defined below
When I debug the code I see the map is empty, other values are populated.

Here is the code

//Java class definitions

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Track {
String title;
String singer;
TestObj test;

public TestObj getTest() {
    return test;
}

public void setTest(TestObj test) {
    this.test = test;
}

public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}

public String getSinger() {
    return singer;
}

public void setSinger(String singer) {
    this.singer = singer;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Track [title=" + title + ", singer=" + singer + "]";
}

}

public class TestObj {
String name;
Map<String,String> testMap;

public Map<String, String> getTestMap() {
    return testMap;
}

public void setTestMap(Map<String, String> testMap) {
    this.testMap = testMap;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

// input JSON string that I pass from POSTMAN

{
    "title": "Enter Sandman",
    "singer": "Metallica",
    "test": {
        "name": "John",
        "testMap": {
            "1": "1",
            "2": "2"
        }
    }
}

My REST POST Service

```
@POST
@Path("/posttrack")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response createTrackInJSON(Track track) {

    String result = "Track  " + track;
    return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();

}
```

Comment: Is the Map {null} or is it an empty map i,e, It is constructed, but has not entries ?

Comment: [its empty map]

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update jersey version to 1.19 and added the below in web.xml to skip use of @XmlRootElement

```
   <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
  <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
  <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
  <version>1.19</version>
</dependency>
```

Older versions of jersey didn't support unmarshalling of hashmap

Answer (score 0):

What is the exact failure? I guess it's the typical error, that it cannot deserialize an interface, you have to define exactly what implementation it there in the JSON, cf. https://stackoverflow.com/a/14402856/5471574

Comment: There is no failure but when I debug I see that my testMap in the TestObj POJO is empty. It shud contain the values that I passed in the input json