# JAX-RS and java.time.LocalDate as input parameter

Tags: java, json, jackson, jax-rs, java-8

Problem using JAX-RS and `java.time.LocalDate` (java8).

I want to pass an object like this into a JAX-RS method using JSON:

```
Person {
  java.time.LocalDate birthDay;
}
```

The exception I get is:

> `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException`: No suitable constructor found for type [simple type, class `java.time.LocalDate`]: can not instantiate from JSON object (need to add/enable type information?) at [Source: `io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl@21cca2c1`; line: 2, column: 3]

How can I create some kind of an interceptor that maps json-dates to `java.time.LocalDate`? I have tried implemented a `MessageBodyReader`, but if the `LocalDate` is a *field* in another class, I have to write a `MessageBodyReader` for each class holding a `LocalDate` (as far as I've understood).

(Java EE7 (only using the javaee-api and don't want any third party dependencies), JAX-RS, Java 8, Wildfly 8.2)

Any suggestions?

Comment: What does the JSON look like coming over the wire?

Comment: It's java. **time** .LocalDate

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Normally I'd say to write a Serializer/Deserializer for Jackson, but since you don't want any other dependencies, you can use a JAXB solutions. Jackson (with Resteasy) comes with support for JAXB annotations. So what we can do is just write an [`XmlAdapter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlAdapter.html) to convert from the String to the `LocalDate`. An example would be something like

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class LocalDateAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, LocalDate> {

    @Override
    public LocalDate unmarshal(String dateString) throws Exception {
        return LocalDate.parse(dateString, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);
    }

    @Override
    public String marshal(LocalDate localDate) throws Exception {
        return DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE.format(localDate);
    }
}
```

You can choose any formatting you want, I just used the [`DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_DATE), which will basically look for this format (2011-12-03).

Then all you need to do is annotate the field for getter of the type

```
public class Person {
    private LocalDate birthDate;

    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(LocalDateAdapter.class)
    public LocalDate getBirthDate() { return birthDate; }

    public void setBirthDate(LocalDate birthDate) { 
        this.birthDate = birthDate;
    }
}
```

If you don't want to clutter your model classes with this annotation, then you can simply declare the annotation at the package level.

In a `package-info.java` file in the same package as the model class(es), add this

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapters({
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(type = LocalDate.class, 
                        value = LocalDateAdapter.class)
})
package thepackage.of.the.models;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapters;
```

---

### Test

```
@Path("/date")
public class DateResource {
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response postPerson(Person person) {
        return Response.ok(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE.format(
                           person.getBirthDate())).build();
    }
}

@Test
public void testResteasy() throws Exception {
    WebTarget target = client.target(
            TestPortProvider.generateURL(BASE_URI)).path("date");
    String person = "{\"birthDate\":\"2015-01-04\"}";
    Response response = target.request().post(Entity.json(person));
    System.out.println(response.readEntity(String.class));
    response.close();
}
```

Result : `2015-01-04`

---

### UPDATE

Also for Jackson (I know the OP said without dependencies, but this is for others), you can use the [jackson-datatype-jsr310](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310) module. See full solution [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28803634/2587435)

Comment: Thank you! It works, but I actually thought there was a simpler way to just create a generic String/LocalDate converter in plain JAX-RS :)

Comment: There is, but not in this context. With JSON to POJO (vice-versa), Jackson will be doing the unmarshalling/marshalling. So we need to tap into Jackson. The context which does allow us to create converters, is say for a `@QueryParam` or `@FormaParam` or `@PathParam` string to pojo conversion, but that is not the case here :-)

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32677962/2587435) for param conversion with a `ParamConverter`. This is for `@QueryParam`, `@FormParam`, and other `@XxxParam`s