# JAXB JSON Jackson unmarshalling array/singleton list

Tags: json, jaxb, jackson

JSON response

Case 1: only one element exists

```
{
"Person": {
    "first": "foo",
    "last": "bar"
}
}
```

Case 2: more than one element exists (ie) proper array type

```
{
"Person": [
    {
        "first": "foo",
        "last": "bar"
    },
    {
        "first": "cow",
        "last": "pal"
    }
]
}
```

JAXB code which generate above responses which i dont have a control over.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class PersonContainer {

@XmlElement
List<Person> personList;
}
```

I use Jackson parser's JAXB feature to unmarshal the JSON to JAXB object. Since there are two types of response is possible , the Jackson parser is not working correctly for Case 1 response.

How do i handle both cases correctly and bind the JSON response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like some custom coding is necessary for the above cases

Map the list with the following

```
          @JsonDeserialize(using=PersonSerializer.class)
          List<Person> personList;
```

Implement PersonSearializer

```
         public class PersonSerializer extends JsonDeserializer<List<Person>>{

public List<Person> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
     ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
     JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jsonParser);
     Iterator<JsonNode>  iterator = node.getElements();

     List<Person> list = new ArrayList<Person>();
     while (iterator.hasNext()){
         JsonNode j = iterator.next();
         Person nr = new Person();
         if (j.get("first") == null) {
             nr.setFirstName(node.get("first").getTextValue()));
             nr.setLastName(node.get("last").getTextValue()));
             list.add(nr);
             break;
         }
         nr.setFirstName(j.get("first").getTextValue()));
         nr.setLastName(j.get("last").getTextValue()));
         list.add(nr);
     }

     return list;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution: replace the JAXB JSON serializer with a better behaved JSON serializer like Jackson. The easy way is to use jackson-jaxrs, which has already done it for you. The class is JacksonJsonProvider. All you have to do is edit your project's web.xml so that Jersey (or another JAX-RS implementation) scans for it. Here's what you need to add:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
  <param-value>your.project.packages;org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs</param-value>
</init-param>
```

And that's all there is to it. Jackson will be used for JSON serialization, and it works the way you expect for lists and arrays.

**It works for me, make sure jackson-jaxrs.jar in your class path.**

Reference:
[How can I customize serialization of a list of JAXB objects to JSON?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2199453/how-can-i-customize-serialization-of-a-list-of-jaxb-objects-to-json)