# Invalid json response from web service, json array string is starting with "!! fully qualified name of class"

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest, http

I am trying to call the REST API of my web service. It is a synchronous call and in response I expect a Json Array of some Object. For ex :-

> [{"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, {"firstName":"Anna",
>   "lastName":"Smith"},  {"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}]

The response is being read by me is using somthing like below -

```
InputStream in = address.openStream();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    result.append(line);
}
System.out.println(result.toString());
```

Now the problem statement is - I am getting a json like this -

> !!com.company.Employee {"firstName":"John", "lastName":"Doe"}, !!com.company.Employee {"firstName":"Anna",
>   "lastName":"Smith"},  !!com.company.Employee {"firstName":"Peter","lastName":"Jones"}

So when I try to pass this string in my JSONArray's constructor it is throwing Exception.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(responseJsonString);
```

The exception is invalid json array it should start with "["

How this can be solved? Kindly share your views, I've already spent 3 hours on it.

Comment: Please show the code of the web service

Comment: Are you sure there are **!!** In the JSON String. That sounds like a problem to me.

Comment: @cricket_007 web service is return array of objects. Ex - Employee[] which contains 3 Employee Objects

Comment: @soufrk That's the issue.

Comment: Your server needs to return a JSON string, not an array of objects. I assume you are using some serialization library to convert that array?

Comment: @cricket_007 The object is serializable and i am using resteasy-jackson-provider as a dependency in my maven pom to convert the Response objects as json

Comment: The problem clearly is that what you get is not JSON. The server needs to be fixed.

Comment: @Henry Even I think the same, though when I try to access some other module in the same server which is having the same Object array return type. It is working fine. Can that be a dependency issue? But as of my past experiences any dependency issue of jackson library will result in exception on the server side rather than malformed json

Comment: If one rest endpoint works, but another doesn't for the same object type, then you'll have to compare the code that builds that response output. Set a breakpoint in the server, if you have to

Comment: Either your server uses some proprietary serialization protocol, or there is a mistake in the implementation/declaration of the API. If the latter is true, we'll need to see the server-side code to help. BTW, paste the URL you are trying to access into the browser's address bar and see what you get to make sure it's not a client issue.

Comment: Is your problem similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/q/10849526/3503018 ??

Comment: @cricket_007 The output is being converted to json using resteasy jackson provider which will convert the object to json by specifying the return media type as application/json. So we cannot put a breakpoint in the conversion code

Comment: @soufrk Nope that is completely different problem.

Comment: You can set a breakpoint before the Response is returned or log the output of manually converting the array with Jackson before resteasy conversion happens

Comment: @cricket_007 did that, still got nothing