# JsonConverter "Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $"

Tags: android, json, arraylist, android-json

I'm getting this exception while trying to populate my listview with JsonConverter

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

This is my JsonConverter class :

```
public class JsonConverter<T> {
public JsonConverter() {
}

public ArrayList<T> toArrayList(String jsonString, Class<T> clazz) {
    GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
    builder.setDateFormat("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss");
    Gson gson = builder.create();
    JsonConverter.ListParameterizedType type = new JsonConverter.ListParameterizedType(clazz);
    ArrayList list = (ArrayList)gson.fromJson(jsonString, type);
    return list;
}

public List<T> toList(String jsonString, Class<T> clazz) {
    ArrayList list = this.toArrayList(jsonString, clazz);
    return list;
}

private static class ListParameterizedType implements ParameterizedType {
    private Type type;

    private ListParameterizedType(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Type[] getActualTypeArguments() {
        return new Type[]{this.type};
    }

    public Type getRawType() {
        return ArrayList.class;
    }

    public Type getOwnerType() {
        return null;
       }
   }
}
```

This is my model class :

```
public class Product implements Serializable {

@SerializedName("pid")
public int pid;

@SerializedName("name")
public String name;

@SerializedName("qty")
public int qty;

@SerializedName("price")
public String description;

@SerializedName("image_url")
public String image_url;

@SerializedName("date")
public String date;
}
```

And I'm calling it like this :

```
private ArrayList<Product> productList;

@Override
public void  processFinish(String s) {
    productList = new JsonConverter<Product>().toArrayList(s, Product.class);
.
.
.
```

Don't Know if I did something wrong here

Comment: can you post the json ?

Answer (score 1):

The error message tells you that while converting the json to a java object the call expected an array in the json but got a string instead.

expected return:

```
[
   "product" : {
       "key" : "value"
   }
]
```

check your json again, it may be a string not an object

Comment: My data are in mysql database , I download them with AsynkTask then pass them into JsonConverter inside my processFinish method .. I had no problem when I was using Eclipse IDE , I get this error when I use android studio , its weird

Comment: you may need [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654042/gson-expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object)

Answer (score 0):

I had a case where I read from a handwritten json file. The json is perfect. However, this error occurred. So I write from a java object to json file, then read from that json file. things are fine. I could not see any difference between the handwritten json and the one from java object. Tried beyondCompare it sees no difference. I finally noticed the two file sizes are slightly different, and I used winHex tool and detected extra stuff below. So the solution for my situation is, make copy of the good json file, paste content into it and use.

[image]