# BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT

Tags: android, android-studio, gson, android-volley

I'm pretty new to GSON,
Few days ago someone suggested to use GSON and here I'am looking for some help.
I am trying to parse this response but I am receiving the said Error..

```
{
  "status": 4,
  "data": {
    "id": 15,
    "user_id": 1,
    "sub_contractor_id": 1,
    "battery_id": 1,
    "user_long": "120.8922933",
    "user_lat": "14.8185964",
    "rider_long": "121.029015",
    "rider_lat": "14.6496133",
    "user_address_location": "313 Bantayan St, Balagtas, 3016 Bulacan, Philippines",
    "complete": 1,
    "created_at": "2017-04-09 15:22:07",
    "updated_at": "2017-04-09 15:26:16",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "user": {
      "id": 1,
      "user_group_id": 3,
      "email": "customer@motolite.com",
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null,
      "deleted_at": null
    },
    "battery": {
      "id": 1,
      "model": "Enduro",
      "size": "DIN44",
      "price": 2000,
      "created_at": null,
      "updated_at": null,
      "deleted_at": null
    }
  }
}
```

I was just getting the "status" part but getting the error.

```
private void fetchPosts() {
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, ENDPOINT, onPostsLoaded, onPostsError) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                params.put("booking_id", "15");
                return params;
            }
        };

        requestQueue.add(request);
    }

    private final Response.Listener<String> onPostsLoaded = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e("TAG", response);
            List<ModelBooking> posts = Arrays.asList(gson.fromJson(response, ModelBooking[].class));
            for (ModelBooking post : posts) {
                Log.e("TAG", post.status);
            }
        }
    };

    private final Response.ErrorListener onPostsError = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e("TAG", error.toString());
        }
    };
```

And for my model.

```
public class ModelBooking {
    @SerializedName("status")
    String status;
}
```

Comment: I believe your question is a duplicate and you can find answer on the Internet. For example, take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9598707/gson-throwing-expected-begin-object-but-was-begin-array

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GSON Expected BEGIN\_ARRAY but was BEGIN\_OBJECT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16654042/gson-expected-begin-array-but-was-begin-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON string is an object (it starts with `{`), not an array (that would start with `[`). So your code would go like this:

```
private final Response.Listener<String> onPostsLoaded = new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override 
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        Log.e("TAG", response);
        ModelBooking post = gson.fromJson(response, ModelBooking.class));
        Log.e("TAG", post.status);
    }  
};
```