# Marshaling list of objects containing maps of objects to JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have this object structure which I'm trying to annotate with Jackson to marshal/unmarshal to a JSON file.

```
public class A {
    List<B> bList;
}

public class B {
    String attr;
    Map<String, C> map;
}

public class C {
    @JsonIgnore
    String name;
    String value;
}
```

`A` has a list of `B`'s and `B` has a map of `C`'s where the key of the map is the `name` attribute of `C`. I want the JSON to look like this if possible:

```
{
    "bList" : [
               {
                   "attr":"itsValue"
                   "KEY_IN_MAP":"VALUE_IN_C",
                   "KEY_2_IN_MAP":"VALUE_2_IN_C"
               }
               ]
}
```

Where `KEY_IN_MAP` is the name of `C` as the key in `B`'s map and `VALUE_IN_C` is the value of the value object in the map. I've tried annotating a put method for the map:

```
@JsonAnySetter
private void put(String name, C value) {
    map.put(name, c);
}
```

But marshaling this gives me:

```
{
    "bList" : [
               {
                   "attr":"itsValue"
                   "KEY_IN_MAP": {
                       "value":"VALUE_IN_C",
                   },
                   "KEY_2_IN_MAP": {
                       "value":"VALUE_2_IN_C"
                   }
               }
               ]
}
```

Is there any way to get the above mapping with Jackson or any other JSON serializing library? My goal is to get rid of the redundancy of writing `"value"` every time and compress the file as much as possible.

The map in `B` could be turned into a list of `C` but I still need the mapping to be

```
{"name" : "value"} for each object C
```

Comment: Why don't you make your `Map<String,String> map` instead of `Map<String, C> map`?

Comment: What about making your `Map<String,C> map` a `List<C>` instead?

Comment: That works, but I kind of want to keep the object structure. It might not make sense for Json, but for my application it's kind of important.

Comment: I think your Class C and Map map in B sort of contradict each other. If you are ignoring name of C, then it probably makes sense to remove C itself from map of B and keep the map simple <String,String>.

Comment: I don't think `List<C>` would work because it would map C as 
`{"name" : "name-value",
"value" : "value-value"}`

Comment: Yeah, it would look like [{"name":"n1","value":"v1"},{"name":"n2","value":"v2"}] if using List<C>. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900132/jax-rs-mapstring-string-to-json-without-the-overhead) thread.

Comment: I'll give it a shot...so much to change. You can add an answer, I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are few suggestions that I have:

1. Make your `Map<String,C>` to be a `Map<String,String>`.
2. You can also make your `Map<String,C>` to be `List<C>`.

Please have a look at the [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900132/jax-rs-mapstring-string-to-json-without-the-overhead) thread which discusses the same.